# CouchDB replication error: {"error":"bad_content_type","reason":"Content-Type must be application/json"}

Tags: json, couchdb, replication

I'm trying to use the *replication* in **CouchDB**.

When I enter the following code :

```
 curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5984/_replicate \
-d ’{"source":"musica","target":"musica-replica"}’
```

I receive the following error:

> {"error":"bad_content_type","reason":"Content-Type must be application/json"}

Can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

As the `reason` said, you need to add a header that looks like: `Content-Type: application/json`

You can add this to curl via the `-H "Content-Type: application/json"` flag.

Comment: if i add -H "Content-Type: application/json" i get :{"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid_json"}
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host '’target'

Comment: It looks like you are using backticks (`) around your JSON data. You should use single quotes (') instead.

Comment: If you have any further issues, please consult documentation on `curl`. You can either google it, or check `man curl` in your terminal.